# Typescript doesn't provide types to argument generics

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I need to describe such a signature so that all types of arguments(before options) are provide into generic of the last argument. Now it looks like this:

```js
public error<Messages extends any[], FormatReturn>(
  ...messages: [...Messages, LoggerOptions<Messages, FormatReturn>]
): void;
```

In the signature of the method itself, you can see that the types are provided

[image]

But in the parameter of the **LoggerOptions** themselves the type is **unknown**

[image]

At the same time, if you change the signature a little and explicitly provide the type, then everything works:

```js
public error<Messages extends any[], FormatReturn>(
  options: LoggerOptions<string | number, FormatReturn>,
  ...messages: Messages
): void;
```

[image]